# Is it possible to listen a React render of a component after compilation (in browser console for example)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, next.js

is there a way to listen to the render event of a react component, once React compiled the code ?

Here is the context. I don't have access to the React source code, but only to the compiled code. I try to change the wording of a button, but my modification is obiously erased by rerender of the component.

Is there something like :

```
document.querySelector('#myButton').addEventListener('render', function(){})
```

Thank you all :)

PS: I'm awared that React isn't made to work like this, but I work threw an injected script from an external js solution.

Comment: So you need this because you want to change 3rd party react app after it renders?

Comment: yep, on each rerender of my button, i'd like to change the innerText of it. As the solution I use to inject my js code is implemented very soon in the page load, my code is executed sooner than the render of the button. That's why I need it :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have control over the React code you could listen for changes in the React container element. On render the children of your `RenderDOM` element changes. Further read: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html

If you are not on a old browser support `MutationObserver` might be also an option https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-tracking-changes-in-the-dom-using-mutationobserver-86adc7446401